# How can I get data of single cell RNA sequence with raw count?

Tags: rna-seq, single-cell, phylogenetics

I am using dataset [GSE85241](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE85241), but I can't find the read counts of the dataset. It only provides with `RPKM` values.

How can I find the read counts of a dataset?

Comment: Hi @KevisLin I think the answer below is the correct answer, haci is an expert. Please consider accepting the answer

Answer (score 1):

If the authors did not provide the raw counts, and I don't think it is compulsory, unfortunately you will need to download the raw data, align and count.